# Issues with HTTPS to HTTP htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having some issues with some .htaccess redirects only working in certain situations.

The code I have is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And here are the results of my tests

https://www.example.com **redirects to** http://example.com

https://example.com **does nothing**

https://www.example.com/page-name **redirects to** http://example.com/page-name

https://example.com/page-name **does nothing**

This is a WordPress site and the .htaccess code sits above the WordPress code. I have also tried it below too and I get the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the site didnt have an SSL attatched to it so the

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

rule was not working correctly.

Because of this I went down this method to fix the redirects and make it work in all of the test cases that I mentioned in the question.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `.htaccess` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I'm assuming that you want `www` forced to not show, since you did not include it in the URL. If that is the case, include this extra condition to force it to not show:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work. I think the lack of SSL on the site was an issue.